# Hiding an external component and calling another external component

Tags: components, hide, external

My index.js file has the following components

---

> ReactDOM.render(   <React.StrictMode>
>
>
>
>    </React.StrictMode>,   document.getElementById('root') );

---

My Navigation Bar was built based on Bootstrap 5 Navbar components. How do I disable  when I click on the search button in the navigation bar and activates the  component ?

Pls help

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is when I click on the search button of the navigation bar, it will disable/hide the <App /> and loads the <Shopping /> automatically

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did. Delete your comment later.